# Select element by passing variable in function - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select all input fields inside a certain element. I pass this element to a function, but I don't know how to go from there:

```
$('._save, .btn-success').click(function(){
   saveForm($('.dashboard_container'));
});

//This functions has to select all the input fields inside the given element
function saveForm(that) {
    var input = $(that, 'input'); //This does not seem to work
    input.each(function(){
       //Do something
    })
}
```

How to chain a variable and a selector together?

Comment: You are looking for all input inside a **button tag**, probably you need to look up on its parent form element....

The best way is to bind the submit event to the form!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contextual selector takes the parameters the other way around to what you've used:

```
function saveForm($that) {
    var $input = $('input', $that);
    $input.each(function(){
       //Do something
    })
}
```

You could also use the `find()` method as you're passing in a jQuery object:

```
var $input = $that.find('input');
```

Comment: Thanks for both options! I tested both options by performance and there isnt much difference. So both methods seem fine!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find all `input` field inside some element `x` then you can use `.find(input)`.

For example:

```
//This functions has to select all the input fields inside the given element
function saveForm(that) {
    var input = $(that).find("input"); //This does not seem to work
    input.each(function(){
       //Do something
    })
}
```

**And you can achieve it without using `.find` as well (the way you were trying to do)**

```
$('._save, .btn-success').click(function(){
   saveForm('.dashboard_container');
});

//This functions has to select all the input fields inside the given element
function saveForm(that) {
    var input = $(that + ' input'); //This does not seem to work
    input.each(function(){
       //Do something
    })
}
```